# How to fix ‘Application terminated’ error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, garbage-collection

I'm developing a libgdx game. When I try to run it on my phone, it compiles and installs successfully but then on the 'Run' console it shows

```
W/linker:libgdx-freetype.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x7eb8
         libgdx-freetype.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x1
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.573ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 161(8KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 873KB/966KB, paused 19.470ms total 34.942ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 35(10KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 4MB/4MB, paused 5.981ms total 2.334s
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 55(10KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(3MB) LOS objects, 34% free, 959KB/1471KB, paused 221.252ms total 526.184ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 27(1952B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 5MB/5MB, paused 100.341ms total 104.980ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 27(1984B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 4MB/4MB, paused 1.403ms total 168.212ms
Application terminated.
```

without showing any specific error

the app closes without even popping the "Unfortunately your app has stopped" dialog box

it closes before loading any Screen at all

Comment: Native crash could be the cause. Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: I don't even know how to go about the debugging process. Could you please enlighten me on it?

Comment: I also discovered that the size of the project folder is about 3 times what I  think it should be. I checked and found some funny folders("generated", "intermediate", "outputs", "tmp) "in the android directory. The "intermediate" folder in turn contains assets and has all my assets again. And there's an apk file "android-debug" within the "outputs" folder. Are all these normal please? I dont think anything is wrong with the source codes because it runs on desktop

Comment: Please I need help on this